# Elastic Search - Accessing a member of an element inside a list

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to elastic search and have a question about accessing an element inside of an element inside of a list. The structure is as follows:

```
{  
   'TestA':'1',
   'TestB':{  
      'TestC':'2',
      'TestD':[  
         {  
            'TestE':'3',
            'TestF':'4'
         },
         {  
            'TestE':'5',
            'TestF':'6'
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

With this following structure I want to return all the results from the query in which `TestF` has a value of `6`. I was wondering if this is possible with the following template.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "TestB.TestD.TestF":'6'
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Would `{"match" : { "TestB.TestD.TestF": '6'}}` be able to search through each element of 'TestD' or would I need to use some other command to iterate through the list? This is with elastic search 5.0. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that would suffice. Make sure that you use `double quotes` for the values if it is a string or `no quotes` if it is a number. JSON standard would require you to make use of double quotes and not single quotes. So its either `{ "TestB.TestD.TestF": "6"}` for string value or `{ "TestB.TestD.TestF": 6 }` if its numeric

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your `match` query should find the results you are looking for. Elasticsearch flattens arrays when it puts them in the inverted index. For more information, check out the docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_how_arrays_of_objects_are_flattened

> Arrays of inner `object` fields do not work the way you may expect.
>   Lucene has no concept of inner objects, so Elasticsearch flattens
>   object hierarchies into a simple list of field names and values.